# How can I render via CoffeeScript in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, render, partial

I was trying to solve this problem for a while with no result.
I've wanted to pass variables and load a render into a div using CoffeeScript in rails 4.
(I'm using SpreeCommerce platform).

**view:**

```
<%= link_to taxonomy.name,root_path+'t/'+tid, {class: "uno", remote: true} %>
```

**controller:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js  # menu.js.coffee.erb
  end
```

**menu.js.erb.coffee:**

```
$('div#productos').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => /shared/products) %>")
```

I'd like to load the page '_products.erb.html' and the partial processes the variables that I give it.  As soon as I know, view and controller are ok, the problem is in *menu.js.erb.coffee*

Any help will be apreciated!

**ADDITIONAL:**

I've modified the extension to .js.coffee.erb.  When I try to run the app, it shows me:

> "undefined method `render' for #<#:0xa70317c>"

I tryied using `<%= raw escape_javascript( render :partial =>...` almost always "render" method give me problems.

**NEW INFO:**

I added `gem 'coffee-script'` to the Gemfile (then '`bundle install`'). 
Now, when I click the link_to, it shows me into the HTML *<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => /shared/products) %>* as a text instead of loading the "partial"... any suggestion please?

Comment: try doing
`<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => /shared/products).html_safe %>`

Comment: I made it working just with .js and putting this file onto the same folder as my view file was.

Answer (score 3):

I [wrote a post about this](http://rubyandrails.herokuapp.com/2015/render-coffeescript-partial-with-erb-in-rails-4/) after struggling through the same problem.

You need to:

- Name it `menu.js.coffee`. Suffixing `.erb` causes it not to be evaluated as CoffeeScript.
- Use `raw` to escape it.

I used these two on my website. Here's how it looks:

`<%= raw render 'path/to/menu.js.coffee' %>`

It still processes ERB within your CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing it from `menu.js.erb.coffee` to `menu.js.coffee.erb`.

Rails will process the file extensions from right to left.  Meaning right now, your file is treated first as coffeescript, then as ruby, and finally as javascript.  It looks like you want to make the ruby substitutions first, then parse the coffeescript into javascript, so that would be `menu.js.coffee.erb`

Comment: I've modified the file as you said and the problem persist. Do you have any idea to solve that? Thank in advanced!

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Could you update your question to include that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should change file name from `menu.js.erb.coffee` to `menu.js.coffee.erb` and you need configuration file as follow, which is a contribution by [cervinka on coffee-rails issue #36](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/36#issuecomment-48191703)

**config/initializers/coffee_erb_handler.rb**

```
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler 'coffee.erb', Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler # without this there will be template not found error

class ActionView::PathResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  EXTRACT_METHODS = %w{extract_handler_and_format_and_variant extract_handler_and_format} # name for rails 4.1 resp. 4.0

  method_name = EXTRACT_METHODS.detect{|m| method_defined?(m) || private_method_defined?(m)}
  raise 'unknown extract method name' if method_name.nil?

  old_method_name = "old_#{method_name}"

  alias_method old_method_name, method_name
  define_method(method_name) do |path, default_formats|
    self.send(old_method_name, path.gsub(/\.js\.coffee\.erb$/, '.js.coffee'), default_formats)
  end
end
```